# MODIFY keyword in SQL SERVER

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

Does the 'MODIFY' keyword exist in SQL SERVER?
I am preparing to an exam and have a question where in all 
options there is 'MODIFY COLUMN' statement. I googled but no result, I
tried to execute the statement but Management Studio did not let me.

Thank you

Comment: Sounds like [ALTER](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190273.aspx)

Comment: http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_alter.asp

Comment: Ya modify column exists there

Comment: Sql Server uses `ALTER`, I believe Oracle uses `MODIFY`.

Comment: What was your google search string?  "sql server keywords" allowed me to find the answer.

Comment: Oh come on, Dan, you can not expect someone pretending a developer to be borderline capable of reading documentation or having any energy to behave like a developer. WHat millenium are you working in. Today it is totally ok to be have like a potato and have other people do your job.

Answer (score 0):

In SQL Server, you can `ALTER TABLE MyTable ALTER COLUMN MyColumn`.  In MySql and Oracle, the syntax is `ALTER TABLE MyTable MODIFY COLUMN`.

See the MSDN docs on [ALTER TABLE](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190273.aspx).

Currently, [MODIFY is not a reserved key word](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189822.aspx) in SQL Server.  However, as the linked article suggests, it is on the list of future reserved words.  Microsoft does not recommend using these words as identifiers.